# Call one controller method from another controller in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have two typescript controllers

```
Controller A
{
   public methodOfA()
   {//do something}
}

Controller B
{
   public methodOfB()
   {//do something}
}
```

How can I achieve something like this

```
Controller B
{
   A.methodOfA();
}
```

Comment: Methods that are to be shared among many controllers, logically belong to services.

Comment: Kobi is right try to move all methods used more than once into services

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
class ControllerA
{
    constructor($scope)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public static methodOfA()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class ControllerB
{
    constructor($scope)
    {
        //do something
        ControllerA.methodOfA();
    }
}
```

Although (as already stated in comments by others) - I do not recommend this approach. Use services for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
     class ControllerA {
           static $inject = ['$http', '$scope','app.services.CommonService'];
           constructor(
                private $http: ng.IHttpService,
                private $scope: ng.IScope, 
                private commonService: app.services.ICommonService){

            }
         //common method call from controller A
         this.commonService.CommonMethod();
        }

     class ControllerB {
            static $inject = ['$http', '$scope','app.services.CommonService'];
            constructor(
                private $http: ng.IHttpService,
                private $scope: ng.IScope, 
                private commonService: app.services.ICommonService){

            }
         //common method call from controller B
         this.commonService.CommonMethod();
       }

 module app.services {   
     //common interface for exposing service
     export interface ICommonService {
         CommonMethod();
     }

     export class CommonService implements ICommonService{
            static $inject = ['$http'];
            constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {

            }

            public CommonMethod(){
                //common method defination here
            }
     }

     factory.$inject = ['$http'];
     function factory($http: ng.IHttpService) {
        return new CommonService($http);
     }

     angular.module('yourApp')
     .factory('app.services.CommonService', factory);
}
```

As Kobi mentioned I used a commom service to expose the common method.